# "Invalid number of arguments" error when trying to update an event

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update calendar events from google apps script. I have the calendar ID, event ID, and objects I am trying to update as a variable:

```
   var eventinfo = {
   "calendarId": calID
      "eventId": eventID,
      "resource": {
        "description": "1234"
      }
   };

 //update the event description and location

   var updater;
   try {
    updater = Calendar.Events.update(eventinfo);
    Logger.log('Successfully updated event: ' + i);
   } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Fetch threw an exception: ' + e);
    }
```

I am getting this error:

> Fetch threw an exception: Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-5 only

Previously, I had attempted to invoke the update method this way `.update(calID, eventID, eventinfo)` where event info was an object with just a description, but that was returning the error saying bad call.

I think I am missing something in my object argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issues:

- First of all, you forgot a comma in the definition of `eventinfo`
  between the first and the second row.
- However, I don't think your approach will work, because you don't
  pass an `event object` in the `Calendar.Events.update()` function. The structure should be like that:

  ```
  Calendar.Events.update(
     event,
     calendarId,
     event.id
   );
  ```

### Solution/Example:

- The following example updates the very first event in the future. In
  particular, it updates the title (summary), description and place but
  feel free modify that if you want:

  ```
  function updateNextEvent() {
    const calendarId = 'primary';
    const now = new Date();
    const events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
      timeMin: now.toISOString(),
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
      maxResults: 1
    });

   var event = events.items[0]; //use your own event object here if you want

   event.location = 'The Coffee Shop';
   event.description = '1234';
   event.summary = 'New event';
   event = Calendar.Events.update(
        event,
        calendarId,
        event.id
      ); 
  }
  ```

Of course, don't forget to switch on the Calendar API from **Resources** => **Advanced Google services**.

### References:

- [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar)

Comment: Thank you! When I loop through your code, I sometimes get the following error depending on which calendar I plug in. With my test calendar, this code works perfectly, but when I try it on a live calendar, my events are being moved around to random dates. I am also getting this error: Fetch threw an exception: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to calendar.events.update failed with error: Invalid sequence value. The specified sequence number is below the current sequence number of the resource. Re-fetch the resource and use its sequence number on the following request.

Comment: @SvenDugojevic thanks for your comment. I am not sure regarding your follow-up question an can't answer at the moment. Could you please create another post so other experts an see the issue you are having? thanks a lot and sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: No problem, I was able to figure out that sequence is an object within an event.

Comment: looks like the document in their example here is outdated:https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update?apix=true#try-it
Thanks for the answer, and for the question